kindly Request for Ramanujan original paper about the distribution of prime factors
I was wondering about the distribution of prime factors and I was looking for the  generalization of PNT, But unfortunately I couldn't find the original proof by Srinivasa Ramanujan which says that:
Theorem (Generalized Prime Number Theorem) Assume that $\pi_m(n)$ is the cardinality of numbers with m prime factors with repetitions included less than or equal $n$, the generalized Prime Number Theorem (GPNT) is:
$$\pi_m(n)\sim \frac{n}{\ln n} \frac{(\ln \ln n)^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}.$$
I would appreciate it if you could help me find Ramanujan's paper.
Thanks in advance

https://drive.google.com/file/d/17wFlx_bdeQyhJg4hBB2W5OCxnCeZtUkz/view?usp=sharing            Does this help?

This was proved earlier, by Landau, in Handbuch der Lehre von Verteilung der Primzahalen, 1909, pp. 203 – 213.
Modern proofs and treatments can be found in Montgomery and Vaughan's Multiplicative Number Theory or Tenenbaum's Introduction to Analytic and Probabilistic Number Theory.
